# Use Dll of the same name for different projects

Tags: vb.net, dll

I am trying to develop a small utility program that will be deployed with other application that we already have. In order to make the utility work, I need to know the connectionString used by the application to access the database.

Since I have old and new applications, they have different ways to connect to the database. So I figured the way I would do it is something like that

- All project will need to implement a dll named "Connect.dll"
- This dll will include one public function name GetConnString. This function will return a string which correspond to the connection string to use to connect to the main database.

What I wanted to do was to simply include the utility in the same folder as the application and use the Connect.dll found within the folder. So far though, unless I copy the original dll found within my utility project, the utility will crash. Is there any way to do this ?

Regards,

Comment: You are asking how to enter DLL Hell.  Very doubtful anybody should open that door for you.  Keep it simple and put the utility in the same directory as the main executable.

Comment: I want to keep it simple.. That being said, I checked for Reflection and it seems to work for me, so I will go for this. Mind you all other application that will use it are developped in-house, so it's easier to manage.

Answer (score 1):

Create a non signed assembly and enforce that all the clients use the same assembly version with (of course) the same signature.

In your utility set the property "Specific Version" to False.

This should do the trick.